# Increment maven project release

Tags: maven, project

I need to increment the project and subprojects release version , whitout create the new SNAPSHOT version.
I tried to use the Maven release plugin, but i found some incompatibility with my scm.
There are a plugin for only increment de buildnumber of a release named like 1.0-buildnumber?

Comment: Which SCM does not work? Which version of Maven do you use? Which version of maven-release-plugin do you use? Apart from that i would recommend to take a look at the [versions-maven-plugin](mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

Comment: I use rtc scm, but I cant use a fixed workspace, for process purpose. I have also tried version-maven plugin: mvn versions:use-releases, but the poms are not modified

Comment: If you tried versions than you do something wrong. Can you show an example pom ?

Comment: <groupId>com.myappl.yyyy0</groupId>
    <artifactId>rtc-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-0-O0000012345</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: There are also 2 subproject                                            <parent>
        <groupId>com.myappl.yyyy0</groupId>
        <artifactId>rtc-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-0-O0000012345</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myappl.yyyy0</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-0-O0000012345</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: This number looks a little bit like the SNAPSHOT versions which is stored on a repository manager so the question is why don't you use SNAPSHOT's and make to an appropriate point in time a release? If you have use versions-maven-plugin please show an small example project which you tried and show what's not the way you expect it.

Comment: I agree that the ideal would be to use a snapshot version and increment the version with the release of the plugin, but unfortunately, I cant with RTC, because you must enter the name of the repository workspace in the scm connect, but in many cases this will change and I should change it manually.
The version rule used is: major.minor-BuildNumber-RFCName (a string that identifies the Request for Change in Artifactory)

Comment: Than you should take a look at [Maven 3.2.1 which has a support for problems like this](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5576).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have wrongly interpreted the functions of the plug-in versions.
I did some tests, and I understand that this plugin allows you to update the pom.xml if the respective release has already been published.
This is not my case, what I need instead is to increase the release by increasing the BuildNumber so that the next phase of development can work using a new version of the project and subprojects.
I understand that this thing can be done only with the Maven release-plugin, but only in the context of using a scm.
If so,Thanks anyway for the support and sorry if I wasted your time.